# translateService.onLangChange.subscribe does not trigger when lang changes in OnInit

Tags: angular, service, subscribe, ngx-translate, date-pipe

So I had translateService.onLangChange.subscribe in a component where it worked fine but a made a separate service were it would subscribe to langChange and set a localeDate for me. But when I change the lang it doesnt register it and does nothing.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLocaleDateFormat();
    this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => this.getLocaleDateFormat());
  }
getLocaleDateFormat() {
    // To add another lang it has to be added to Languages bellow to match the locale_id of the lang and in main module it has to be imported and registered
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(Languages[this.translateService.currentLang]);
    this.currLang = Languages[this.translateService.currentLang];
    console.log('locale-date-adapters currLang: ' + this.currLang);
    return this.currLang;
  }
```

also everytime the lang change I'd like my component to get that value from getLocaleDateFormat(), without having

```
this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => thisLocaleDateAdapterService.getLocaleDateFormat());
```

in my component. I tried subscribing to it but got an error that it isn't a function.

this is what I tried:

```
this.localeDateAdapterService.getLocaleDateFormat().subscribe(currLang => this.currLang = currLang);
```

I basically want it to be listening to getLocaleDateFormat and change the value when it changes.

UPDATE:
I just realized that the problem is in the OnInit thats not trigering the lang change. LangChange is trigger inside the service in function but not in OnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to put the service that is calling the onLang in the main module Provider.